# WS 2012 R2 NIC TEAM

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I'm looking at creating a 3 NIC Team for my hyper-v servers
I was wondering is it actually possible to do a 3 x NIC team or is it only possible to do it in 2's?

I have no lab equipment to test this on so I'd appreciate your advice as I want to configure this in production in less than a month.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 2):

According to [Windows 2012 Server NIC TEaming overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831648.aspx): Windows Server® 2012 supports up to 32 network adapters in a team

Comment: Hi Sergey, Thank you for the reply. The question I was asking is do they have to be in two's or can I add an odd number of NIC's ?

Comment: You can add ANY number (up to 32) of NICs to teaming. And that number does not have to be even. You can create teaming even with single NIC (but with no fault tolerance).